# Laravel Eloquent can't use where not to query relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

**My problem:** I can't seem to use `where('user_id', '<>', Auth::id()` on a relationship collection using Laravel's Eloquent ORM.

In Laravel 5, I have a database with the following schema:

```
| USERS    | JOBS    | CONVERSATIONS | MESSAGES        | CONVERSATION_USER |
| id       | id      | id            | id              | conversation_id   |
| username | user_id | job_id        | conversation_id | user_id           |
| password | title   |               | user_id         |                   |
|          |         |               | message         |                   |
```

and with the following relationships:

```
User model:
$jobs = $this->hasMany('job');
$messages = $this->hasMany('message');
$conversations = $this->belongsToMany('conversation');

Job model:
$user = $this->belongsTo('user');
$conversations = $this->hasMany('conversation');
$messages = $this->hasManyThrough('message', 'conversation');

Conversation model:
$job = $this->belongsTo('job');
$messages = $this->hasMany('message');
$user = $this->belongsToMany('user');

Message model:
$user = $this->belongsTo('user');
$conversation = $this->belongsTo('conversation');
```

I'm trying to get the number of messages for a job, which have not been posted by the authenticated user. My code is:

```
// Load all of the jobs which relate to the logged in user
$jobs = Job::with(['messages'])->where('user_id', Auth::id())->OrderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();

foreach ($jobs as $job)
{
    // Count all messages that have not been sent by the logged in user
    echo $job->messages->where('user_id', '<>', Auth::id())->count().'<br />';
}
```

However I just cannot get the count function to work.

Comment: Try changing `messages->` to `messages()->` within your loop.

Comment: @MattBurrow you need to put your comment as the answer as it works!

Comment: answer has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change `messages->` to `message()->` within your loop, you will be able to re-query your relation set.